# How to find duplicate rows where 4 colums are matching and 3 are not

Tags: sql-server

I have table with the following schema

```
TransNo|TransId|createddate|order|tank|meter|quantity
```

We have different values for 1st 3 columns, but the next 4 are same.
I want to get `TransNo` where the last four (`order`, `tank`, `meter` and `quantity`) are same to delete duplicates if they exist.

Comment: You can use a GROUP BY TransNO, order qty meter in your query.

Comment: @Vishal, sorry I rejected your edit. It was a mistake. I guess it's not possible to remove a rejection.

Comment: @Zboson its ok.. np :)

Comment: Show us what have you tried!

Answer (score 0):

To only find TransNo with duplicate 'last four':

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TransNo, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [order],tank,meter,quantity) cnt
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT TransNo 
FROM cte 
WHERE cnt>1
```

To delete rows with the same 'last four' and TransNo > min(TransNo) for this 'last four':

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [order],tank,meter,quantity ORDER BY TransNo) AS rn
    FROM your_table)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with below query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ABC
 WHERE order1 IN (SELECT order1 
                   FROM order1 GROUP BY
                   order1 
                   HAVING COUNT(TransNo) > 1)
AND
tank IN (SELECT tank 
           FROM tank 
         GROUP BY tank 
        HAVING COUNT(TransNo) > 1)
AND
meter IN (SELECT meter 
          FROM meter 
          GROUP BY meter 
          HAVING COUNT(TransNo) > 1)
AND
quantity IN (SELECT quantity
               FROM quantity
              GROUP BY quantity
             HAVING COUNT(TransNo) > 1)
```

Comment: Your "Note" is incorrect. You can surround the column name with brackets [order].

Answer (score 0):

You can SELECT duplicate values by using GROUP BY into a temp-table and then use that result to aggregate TransNo:

```
SELECT [order], tank, meter, quantity
INTO #duplicates
FROM <your table> 
GROUP BY [order], tank, meter, quantity
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

SELECT DISTINCT b.TransNo, c.TransNo --Optional: , b.[order], b.tank, b.meter, b.quantity
FROM #duplicates a
INNER JOIN <your table> b ON
    AND a.[order] = b.[order]
    AND a.tank = b.tank
    AND a.meter = b.meter
    AND a.quantity = b.quantity
INNER JOIN <your table> c ON
    AND a.[order] = c.[order]
    AND a.tank = c.tank
    AND a.meter = c.meter
    AND a.quantity = c.quantity
    AND b.TransNo <> c.TransNo
```

Comment: I want to have lets two trans values where the other rows   values are matching . With duplicates temp table I can find the transaction numbers where the count is more than 1 but I need the transaction number where its matching

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but try un-commenting the "Optional"-part in my second SELECT. That will show you which TransNo's match on which data.

Comment: I mean suppose transno in row 1 is matching with transno in row2 and the values in row1 is 1 and in row2 its 2  so I need to get  1,2

Comment: Edited answer to match your request

Comment: @Poonam Singhania, I edited my answer again when I noticed that createdate shouldn't be included in the comparison. Try the above code and it should work.